# What is known about the largest prime divisor of the product of $k$ consecutive integers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

Take $k$ consecutive composite integers from a prime gap. What is known about the largest prime divisor of their product?

It seems to me that except for the triplet $(8,9,10)$ and the pair $(8,9)$ , this largest prime divisor is always larger than $2k$, but I could not find an elementary (my level) proof.

As $k$ grows it seems that the sharpness of $2k$ as lower bound is lost, therefore I expect that there should exist a more suitable lower bound, from which an "easy" argument for the minoration by $2k$ would follow.

The question is essentially the same as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495443/2k-as-a-lower-bound-for-the-largest-prime-divisor-of-binomial-coefficient-bi) from MSE but it did not get any answer. I could only find messy $k$-specific arguments for $k$ up to $4$ which I hope are correct.

Comment: Do you have any reference to a "nonelementary" proof?

Comment: @Wojowu.   No, but I am not professional mathematician, so my knowledge of (and access to) math literature is very limited. If you know of relevant papers, I 'd be interested.

Comment: I was asking because when you said "...I could not find an elementary (my level) proof.", I thought you might have found a hard proof and you were just looking for a simpler one.

Comment: You might be interested in a paper of Filip Najman at http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.3710 .  The largest prime divisor of the product n+1 to n +f(k) is looked at and shown to be larger than k when n is larger than k.  f(k) is pretty small and conjectured to be O(log(k)^2).  So you don't need as many as k consecutive integers.  Gerhard "Sees This As Smooth Intervals" Paseman, 2015.11.02

Comment: @Gerhard   That is very interesting, thanks. Probably above my current level though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There have been several investigations into the largest prime factor of a product of consecutive integers; the Sylvester--Schur theorem is an early example. Here is a survey by Shorey and Tijdeman: https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~tijdeman/shoretij.pdf

In

Laishram, Shanta(6-TIFR-SM); Shorey, T. N.(6-TIFR-SM)
The greatest prime divisor of a product of consecutive integers. 
Acta Arith. 120 (2005), no. 3, 299–306

it is shown that $$ P(n(n+1) \cdots (n+k-1)) > 2k $$ as long as $n > \max\{k+13, \frac{279}{262}k\}$.

Note that for large $k$, the lower bound condition on $n$ is implied by your hypothesis that all of $n, n+1, \dots, n+k-1$ are composite; so this answers your question for large $k$. (And for bounded $k$, it reduces checking your conjecture to a finite computation.)

There is more good news: the MathSciNet review records that "the proof is elementary".

Comment: If the numbers are composite, can we give a constant lower bound on $n+k-1$, as long as $n>2k$?